# using variable in jQuery load, to load partial html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to load a partial HTML file using AJAX like the below, however the page loads completely and not just the selector. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function(){
    $('#post-list a').click(function(e){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#ajax-div').load(url "#post");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see how the code works at all as you have a syntax error; you need to concatenate `url` and `"#post"` together like this: `url + " #post"`. Note that the space before the `#` is important. Without it `post` will be interpreted as a fragment on the URL, not as a selector.

Comment: .load(url+"#post")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JQuery documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

in you code:

```
$('#ajax-div').load(url "#post");
```

should be:

```
$('#ajax-div').load(url+" #post");
```

I am assuming the missing + is a typo, but the space between url and #post is important!